# Calculating the conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A new computer program consists of two modules, A and B. First model contains an error with probability 0.2 and second contains an error with probability 0.4. An error in the first module alone cause the program to crash with probability 0.5, and for the second module, it is 0.8. If there are errors in both modules, the programs crashes with a probability of 0.9. Suppose the program crashed, what is the probability of error in both the modules?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

The program crashes, event C, iff there is (error in A and not in B) or (error in B and not in A) or (errors in both A and B). Thus, 
P(C) = P(C n A n not B) + P(C n not A n B) + P(C n A n B).

P(C n A n not B) = P( C | A n not B) P(A n not B) = P( C | A n not B) P(A)P(not B) = 0.5(0.2)(0.6) = 0.06. This is because A and B are independent ( the fact that there is error in module A does not determine whether there is error in B).

In similar way,
P(C n not A n B) = P( C | not A n B) P(not A n B) = P( C | not A n B) P(not A)P(B) = 0.8(0.8)(0.4) = 0.256.

And
P(C n A n B) = P(C | A n B)P(A n B) = P(C | A n B)P(A)P(B) = 0.9(0.2)(0.4) = 0.072. Hence

P(C) = 0.06 + 0.256 + 0.072 =0.388.

Now, what you are to find is

P(A n B | C) = P(C| A n B) P(A n B) / P(C) = P(C| A n B) P(A)P(B) / P(C) = 0.9(0.2)(0.4)/(0.388) = 0.1856.